Go benchmarking issue
I'm trying to benchmark a custom hashmap implementation -> https://github.com/dmarro89/go-redis-hashtable.
This struct currently has 3 methods : Set, Get and Delete.
In the Set Benchmark, I prepare the data and then invoke the Set method, attempting to measure the execution time and the memory allocation.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/dmarro89/go-redis-hashtable/datastr"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func BenchmarkSet(b *testing.B) {
    var d = datastr.NewDict()
    insertedElements := make(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Printf("Inserting elements %d times \n", b.N)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        key := randomString(20)
        value := randomString(100)
        insertedElements[key] = value
    }
    b.ResetTimer()
    for key, value := range insertedElements {
        b.StartTimer()
        err := d.Set(key, value)
        b.StopTimer()
        assert.NoError(b, err, fmt.Sprintf("Error adding element {%s, %+v} to dictionary: %v", key, value, err))
    }
}

The problem is that if I try to change the way I prepare the data for the tests (the first loop) the benchmarks results changes. This leads me to believe that the memory allocation for preparing the data is included in the benchmark results.
How can I exclude the data preparation time and memory allocation from the benchmark results?

Your code is flawed. If you want to benchmark Dict.Set you have to call Dict.Set b.N times (or a multiple thereof). Your current (wrong) code loops b.N time during data preparation and not during what you want to benchmark. Of course the loop is implicitely executed b.N times, but that is wrong from a conceptual viewpoint. Just pregenerate a large enough insertedElements before, e.g. during init.

Also note that your code doesn't properly benchmark something that is reproducible. Inserting a set of random elements is something that is sensible to benchmark, but not if the size of this set varies from run to run. A better approach would be to to benchmark inserting a set of 10, 30, 100, 300, 1'000, 3'000, ... elements while each iteration uses the exact same set of elements.

Also note that inserting random keys of length 20 will result in almost uniqe keys and you probably should have benchmarks for inserting guaranteed unique keys, inserting exactly 20% non-unique keys and inserting only non-unique keys to clearly see what type of operation is how fast. Your current attempt at benchmarking glosses over all sort of differences like size and percentage of unique keys (i.e. Set-New vs. Replace operations).

Hi @Volker thanks for your answer. I got your point and I've updated the tests.
Here's the link ->  https://github.com/dmarro89/go-redis-hashtable/blob/main/test/benchmarks_test.go.
What do you think ?

No, this is still not okay. Each func Benchmark... must iterate b.N times. Do smth like func BenchmarkSet100(b *testing.B) { for i := 0; i<b.N; i++ { dict:=datastr.NewDict(); for key, value := range Set100 { dict100.Set(key, value) }}}. If you are concerned about the overhead of NewDict: Benchmark and optimize that function alone first.

ok @Volker so are you saying that something like this :
 for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
  dict100 = datastr.NewDict()
  b.ResetTimer()
  for key, value := range Set100 {
   dict100.Set(key, value)
  }
  b.StopTimer()
 }
}```
Is a good way to benchmark the set operation. 
It is really a long operation -> if N = 1000000000, it repeat the same operation for 100000000 times.

No. Stop that reset timer stuff. Decide what you want to measure and do that b.n times. Take a look at the benchmarks in the stdlib.

First of all, you need reproducible results. Create a deterministic pseudo-random number generator:
    rnd := rand.New(rand.NewSource(42)) //nolint:gosec

and use that:
func randomString(rnd *rand.Rand, n int) string {
    p := make([]byte, n)
    rnd.Read(p)

    return string(p)
}

Note that math/rand/v2 is available and should generally be used. I didn't bother for this example.
Next, since you want deterministic order, generate your test data as an array, not a map:
    type keyValue struct{ Key, Value string }

    insertedElements := make([]keyValue, 0, b.N)

    rnd := rand.New(rand.NewSource(42)) //nolint:gosec
    for range b.N {
        key := randomString(rnd, 20)
        value := randomString(rnd, 100)
        insertedElements = append(insertedElements, keyValue{Key: key, Value: value})
    }

now, after set up, reset the timer and execute your benchmark:
    d := datastr.NewDict()

    b.ResetTimer()

    for _, kv := range insertedElements {
        if err := d.Set(kv.Key, kv.Value); err != nil {
            b.Errorf("Error adding element {%v, %v} to dictionary: %v", []byte(kv.Key), []byte(kv.Value), err)
        }
    }

The if should have negligible impact, less than calling stop/start. Try the benchmark without error checking to verify.
All together in one file:
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "testing"

    "github.com/dmarro89/go-redis-hashtable/datastr"
)

func BenchmarkSet(b *testing.B) {
    type keyValue struct{ Key, Value string }

    insertedElements := make([]keyValue, 0, b.N)

    rnd := rand.New(rand.NewSource(42)) //nolint:gosec
    for range b.N {
        key := randomString(rnd, 20)
        value := randomString(rnd, 100)
        insertedElements = append(insertedElements, keyValue{Key: key, Value: value})
    }

    d := datastr.NewDict()

    b.ResetTimer()

    for _, kv := range insertedElements {
        if err := d.Set(kv.Key, kv.Value); err != nil {
            b.Errorf("Error adding element {%v, %v} to dictionary: %v", []byte(kv.Key), []byte(kv.Value), err)
        }
    }
}

func randomString(rnd *rand.Rand, n int) string {
    p := make([]byte, n)
    rnd.Read(p)

    return string(p)
}

Note that, how @Volker correctly remarks, “inserting random keys of length 20 will result in almost unique keys”, so you might not benchmark what you think you do.

Thanks @eik for your feedback.
I've updated the structure of the tests as suggested -> https://github.com/dmarro89/go-redis-hashtable/blob/main/test/benchmarks_test.go
Please, feel free to add your feedback.
